# MySQL replication - Query is replicated even if explicitely ignored

Tags: mysql, replication

I have a MySQL Master 5.0.77 replicating on a slave 5.5.13.
So I'm using STATEMENT based replication.

I have a query 'CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE blah' that is replicated even if it's not in the "replicate-do-table" or "Replicate_Wild_Do_Table" list.

The database name is not explicitly specified in the query, default database used.

In addition to that, I also have "Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table" set to not replicate this table.

How is it going through ?

Thx

edit: the query contain a UNION, maybe the replication work differently with 5.5 ?

Answer (score 2):

By default, all temporary tables are replicated. Take a look at [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication-features-temptables.html) for more details.

Comment: But there's still the replicate_ignore_tables that should have caught the query.